# Flutter Stable 1.22.6 can't build apk

Tags: flutter, apk, version

I'm  trying to build apk with flutter stable version 1.22.6 but keep getting error below;

**Error**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\emirk\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3dd4f179ab5210ef1c86848f5b37a403\play-services-ads-lite-19.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-38:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 15s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      16,4s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

So i ran Flutter doctor and here's result of flutter doctor,

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.746], locale tr-TR)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Any idea why is it happenning?

Comment: have you enables mutidex? https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android/

Answer (score 0):

Migrate your code to AndroidX hope it will solve the issue https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

Comment: it's already using androidX

Comment: The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
this describes that it doesn't use it copy whole project to new project